# How to sort items in view by field of lookup entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is there any way to enable sorting on column which represents field of related entity?

For example, Case contains one lookup field - Contact. In view I added FullName and Email of Contact. Header in view of these two columns is not clickable (Sort is not enabled).

Comment: There is no any 'sorting' options related on these fields. I'm pretty sure (90%) that this is not possible, but I need confirmation for 100% sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Sorting is not possible for fields of a referenced entity.
If you really need this, you have to build a custom view (html page) or for example a report